# Error en el switch case que no entiendo

Tags: java, menú, método

He hecho este programa que es una pila.En este caso decidí hacer un menú en el que llamaba a los métodos pero a la hora de llamarlos no me funciona, me marca mal todos los cases.

Creo que mi error es al llamar a los métodos pero no entiendo cual es mi error. Agradecería una ayuda, gracias. (No es necesario que me lo resolváis bien sino que me gustaría entender porque lo hago mal y así no volver a cometer errores.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pila_1 {

    class Nodo{
        int info;
        Nodo sig;
    }

    private Nodo raiz;

    public Pila_1(){
        raiz=null;
    }

    public void insertar(int x){
        Nodo nuevo;
        nuevo=new Nodo();
        nuevo.info=x;
        if(raiz!=null){
            nuevo.sig=raiz;
            raiz=nuevo;
        }
        else{
            nuevo.sig=null;
            raiz=nuevo;
        }
    }
    public int extraer(){
        if(raiz!=null){
             int informacion=raiz.info;
             raiz=raiz.sig;
             return informacion;
        }else{
             return Integer.MAX_VALUE;   
        }
    }
    public void imprimir(){
        Nodo recorrer=raiz;
        while(recorrer!=null){
            System.out.println(recorrer.info+"---");
            recorrer=recorrer.sig;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        int op;
        System.out.println("Que opcion desea tomar: 1-Insertar   2-Extraer  3-Imprimir");
        op=entrada.nextInt();
        do{
            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Declara una variable a introducir :");
                    int variable;
                    variable=entrada.nextInt();
                    insertar(variable);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    extraer();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imprimir();
                    break;
            }

        }while(op==1||op==2||op==3);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error exactamente? (Aparte de tener un bucle infinito o nulo

Comment: Me sigue marcando mal los métodos al llamarlos, te digo lo que me marca de error= non static method extraer cannot be referenced from a static context. Me marca eso en todos los métodos llamados en el menú.

Comment: Ahh, eso es porque no puedes acceder a metodos no estaticos desde un contexto estatico

Comment: y que solución puedo usar?

Comment: Ponerlos como static, ya te he publicado la solución como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando acceder a unos métodos de tu clase no declarados como estáticos desde un método que sí lo es. El compilador te está avisando que no puedes hacer eso con el error que has comentado. Para solucionarlo, tienes dos opciones:

1. **Declarar esos métodos como estáticos**: en mi opinión, es un error hacer eso puesto que estarías cometiendo un grave error de diseño de tus objetos. El static tiene un efecto "vírico" y si optas por esta solución acabas convirtiendo a estático todos los métodos que declares. Además, cuando empiezas a extender el uso de static, es fácil tener problemas si creas diversas instancias de tu clase. Resumiendo mucho, debes contestar a "¿Tiene sentido que alguien use este método si antes no se ha creado una instancia de la clase que lo define?". Si la respuesta es afirmativa, puedes declararlo como static; si es negativa, no debes hacerlo.
2. **Instanciar tu clase en el método main**: en vez de declarar los métodos como static, los dejas como inicialmente los has definido y creas una instancia de Pila_1, usando la misma para gestionar la ejecución de tu programa.

El código quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pila_1 pila = new Pila_1();
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    int op;
    System.out.println("Que opcion desea tomar: 1-Insertar   2-Extraer  3-Imprimir");
    op=entrada.nextInt();
    do{
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Declara una variable a introducir :");
                int variable;
                variable=entrada.nextInt();
                pila.insertar(variable);
                break;
            case 2:
                pila.extraer();
                break;
            case 3:
                pila.imprimir();
                break;
        }

    } while(op==1||op==2||op==3);
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha encantado, mil gracias respondes a mi duda tal y como queria.

Comment: Me alegro :) Sería de agradecer en ese caso que marcases mi respuesta como la correcta, gracias :)

Answer (score -2):

Simplemente marca los metodos a usar como static

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pila_1 {

    class Nodo{
        int info;
        Nodo sig;
    }

    private Nodo raiz;

    public Pila_1(){
        raiz=null;
    }

    public static void insertar(int x){
        Nodo nuevo;
        nuevo=new Nodo();
        nuevo.info=x;
        if(raiz!=null){
            nuevo.sig=raiz;
            raiz=nuevo;
        }
        else{
            nuevo.sig=null;
            raiz=nuevo;
        }
    }
    public static int extraer(){
        if(raiz!=null){
             int informacion=raiz.info;
             raiz=raiz.sig;
             return informacion;
        }else{
             return Integer.MAX_VALUE;   
        }
    }
    public static void imprimir(){
        Nodo recorrer=raiz;
        while(recorrer!=null){
            System.out.println(recorrer.info+"---");
            recorrer=recorrer.sig;
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        int op;
        System.out.println("Que opcion desea tomar: 1-Insertar   2-Extraer  3-Imprimir");
        op=entrada.nextInt();
        do{
            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Declara una variable a introducir :");
                    int variable;
                    variable=entrada.nextInt();
                    insertar(variable);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    extraer();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imprimir();
                    break;
            }

        }while(op==1||op==2||op==3);
    }
}
```